# php - Cambiar color de texto según el valor obtenido

Tags: php, wordpress

Necesito su ayuda. Tengo esta línea y quisiera que el valor "open" se visualice de color verde y el valor "Closed" de color rojo. Gracias por el apoyo.

```
<span><?php echo $open_now ? __( 'Open', 'my-listing') : __( 'Closed', 'my-listing') ?></span>
```

Comment: <span><?php echo $open_now ? __( 'Open', 'my-listing') : __( 'Closed', 'my-listing') ?></span>

Comment: ESA LÍNEA ponla en tu pregunta editala y agregalo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podes ponerle clases al span para identificar un estado u otro y después con `.css` les pones los estilos verde o rojo según corresponda.

Desde PHP:

```
<span class="is_<?php echo $open_now ? 'open' : 'closed'; ?>">
  <?php echo $open_now ? __( 'Open', 'my-listing') : __( 'Closed', 'my-listing') ?>
</span>
```

Y después en los estilos agregás lo siguiente:

```
.is_open {
  color: green;
}

.is_closed {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Genial! resolviste mi problema. Gracias!

Comment: De nada, si realmente te sirvió, no olvides de marcar como correcta la respuesta. Saludos.